# fatal error LNK1136: invalid or corrupt file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mapi

I am getting **lib\MAPI.lib :fatal error LNK1136: invalid or corrupt file**. What can be the done for this?

I tried cleaning the solution & also tried searching this file but none of them worked.
What can be done for this problem?

Comment: Get a `MAPI.lib` file which isn't invalid or corrupt. But seriously, give us a hand here; no one's psychic. Please read [this](http://sscce.org/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MAPI.lib is a system library installed as part of Visual Studio. Like any other file on your system, it could have become corrupted through various means (hard drive problem, unclean shutdown, etc.). Try doing a repair install of Visual Studio:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx#repair

If that doesn't work, you could also try reinstalling.